# CytoscapeJS calling setState function in React

Tags: reactjs, cytoscape.js

I am trying to make a nodemap, visualized with cytoscapejs in react.
When trying to run the following code i get the error "this.handleTextChange is not a function".
Is it not allowed to call a function from within a const? It compiles just fine, but when clicking a node, the error occurs.

```
import React from 'react';
const cytoscape = require( 'cytoscape' );
const cycola = require( 'cytoscape-cola' );

cytoscape.use( cycola );

export class NodeBox extends React.Component {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );
        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind( this );
        this.state = {
         description: ''
      }

      this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);

    }
    handleTextChange(text){
      this.setState({description: text});
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        const cy = cytoscape( {

            container: document.getElementById( 'cy' ),
            boxSelectionEnabled: false,
            elements: this.props.elements[0],
            style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
              .selector('node')
                .css({
                  'label': 'data(name)',
                  'width':'data(size)',
                  'height':'data(size)',
                  'border-width':'3',
                  'border-color': '#618b25',
                  'background-fit':'cover',
                  'background-image': 'data(img)'

                })

              .selector('edge')
                .css({
                  'curve-style': 'unbundled-bezier',
                  'control-point-distance': '20px',
                  'control-point-weight': '0.5', // '0': curve towards source node, '1': towards target node.
                  'width': 1, //
                  'line-color': '#618B25',
                  'target-arrow-color': '#618B25',
                  'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
                })


          },
          'layout':{
            'name': 'cola', 'maxSimulationTime': 0
          }

      );

      cy.panningEnabled( false );

      cy.on('tap', 'node', function(evt){
          var node = evt.target;
          if (node.id() !== 1){
            console.log(node.data('description'));

            this.handleTextChange(node.data('description'));
          }
        });
      cy.panningEnabled( false );
    }
    render() {
        return <div> <div style ={{'height':300, 'width':'100%'}} id="cy"> </div><h1 id="desc" style={{textAlign:"center"}}>{this.state.description}</h1></div>;
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to work around this without setting state?

Comment: You never need to bind `componentDidMount`. Also, "an error occurs", which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You don't need to bind componentDidMount to this. So, remove the following

`this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind( this );`

2) Use arrow function to lexically bind this, the value of this remains the same as the context in which the arrow function is defined. So, change to the following

```
cy.on('tap', 'node',(evt) => {
      var node = evt.target;
      if (node.id() !== 1){
        console.log(node.data('description'));

        this.handleTextChange(node.data('description'));
      }
});
```

Aside : Most emitters (like EventEmitter in Node, jQuery listeners, or Cytoscape) are going to use `Function.apply()` to set `this` in the callback to the emitter object --- which is why (2) is necessary.